# How to show multiple selected values of selectbox in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to show multiple selected values in laravel5.3 form

```
{!! Form::select('category[]', $categories['all_cat']['categories'], null,['multiple' => 'multiple'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'category']) !!}
```

Comment: This should enable you to select multiple values from the select input. Do you mean you want to display the selected ones, for example when editing the record?

Comment: Thanks for interest .  I am already solve it at my end. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
{!! Form::select('category[]', $categories['all_cat']['categories'], null, ['multiple' => true, 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'category']) !!}
```